# list of primes for which 2 is a primitive root

Tags: nt.number-theory, primitive-roots

I am looking for a list of primes $\le N$ for which 2 is a primitive root, with $N$ as large as available. I know of a [table of smallest primitive roots for all primes below 1000](http://users.uoi.gr/abeligia/NumberTheory/NT2015/PrimitiveRoots.pdf), from which such a list can be extracted when $N=1000$, but I am interested in much larger $N$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sequence of primes for which 2 is a primitive root is [OEIS A001122](http://oeis.org/A001122). It contains a [list](http://oeis.org/A001122/b001122.txt) for the first 10.000 entries, which goes up to $N=310091$. I'm not sure if that is sufficient for you, but it's at least a first step.